# Min and Max from every group

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table

**location:**

- location_id
- address

**itransfile:**

- id
- transactionNumber
- location_id
- itemName
- quantity

I want to get maximum and minimum sold items by locations.

```
HighestItemName     HighQauntity    LowestItemName      LowQuantity     LocationName

Chicken Burger      50              Tako                5               Gulshan
Chicken Burger      100             Tikka               10              Nipa
Pasta               150             Cheese Burger       12              Liyari
Pizza               200             Chicken Burger      3               F.B.Area
```

The query I've done so far:

```
SELECT t.itemName as HighestItemName, sum(t.quantity) as HighQuantity, l.address LocationName
    from itransfile as t join locations as l
    on t.location_id = l.location_id 
    where t.location_id IN(1,2,3,4)
    group by t.location_id
```

I don't know how will get `max` and `min` items from every group.

**Sample Data:**

```
ID  TransNumber ItemName        Quantity location_id
1   1234        Chicken Burger  3           1
2   1234        Cheese Burger   1           1
3   1235        Sandwich        4           2
4   1332        Salad           1           4
5   14537       Tikka           1           3   
6   1236        Roll            3           2
7   1333        Biryani         2           4


location_id     address
1               Gulshan
2               Nipa
3               Liyari
4               F.B.Area
```

Comment: Provide your proper table definitions and sample data set to get the desired result set

Comment: Ok, let me collect it to post here

Comment: Do you need it in one query or can you run two queries?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Unfortunately i want it in one query. if possible

Comment: I believe you can get what you want by using min and max functions: SELECT t.itemName as HighestItemName, sum(t.quantity) as HighQuantity, min(t.quantity) as minQuantity, max(t.quantity) as maxQuantity

Comment: question: can one location_id have multiple rows for 1 item?
So ID 1 is a customer buying 3 chicken burgers. If new customer buys chickenburger at location_id 1, is that a new row or do you update Quantity=4 for ID 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you may be looking for if you need it in one query ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27c52/2)):

```
select
  l.address,
  imax.itemName max_item, max_min.max_q,
  imin.itemName min_item, max_min.min_q
FROM
  (select
    i.location_id, MAX(i.quantity) max_q, MIN(i.quantity) min_q
  FROM
    itransfile i
  GROUP BY
    i.location_id) as max_min
  LEFT JOIN itransfile imax ON (max_min.max_q = imax.quantity)
  LEFT JOIN itransfile imin ON (max_min.min_q = imin.quantity)
  LEFT JOIN location l ON (max_min.location_id = l.location_id)
GROUP BY
  l.location_id
```

It looks for min/max values and then looks up the item name and location address. The `GROUP_CONCAT` makes sure that when there are more items with the same min/max quantity, you get all of them.

Alternatively you can get rid of the `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` and get all the items in rows if you need to further process them.

Comment: can you please remove group concat, if there are multiple items with same quantity then i only want one item

Comment: You just remove the `GROUP_CONCAT` and it gives you itemName. I believe the itemName will be given randomly - in this case every time you run the query the result may be different if there are several items with the same quantity.